# How to update values of elements in map C++

Tags: c++, object, dictionary, stdmap, stock

I am making a program and I need to get and Object from a map and update values of the Object. Here is some of my code from my data class:

```
StockHolding& StockData::findHolding(const string &ticker) {
 StockHolding var;
 var = portfolio[ticker];
 return var;
}
```

Here is code from the data.h class:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, StockHolding>StockMap;
class StockData
{
 private: StockMap portfolio;
 private: string portfolioFile;
 private: void splitString(vector<string> &, const string &, char);
public:
 StockData();
 StockData(const string &);
 void addHolding(StockHolding &);
 void readPortfolioFile();
 StockHolding& findHolding(const string &);
 void display();
 void writePortfolioFile(); 
};
```

And here is code from my Driver class:

```
main(){
 StockHolding sH = sD.findHolding("APPL");
 sH.setPrice(5);
 sD.findHolding("APPL").setShares(15);
 sD.display();
 sD.writePortfolioFile();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `StockData::findHolding` you're declaring a local variable `var`, which has nothing to do with the element in the map, so modifying on it won't have any effect.

And `var` is returned by reference, but `var` will be destroyed when get out of the function, then the returned reference will be dangled.

You might return the element of `map` directly by reference:

```
StockHolding& StockData::findHolding(const string &ticker) {
 return portfolio[ticker];
}
```

Then

```
StockHolding& sH = sD.findHolding("APPL");
sH.setPrice(5);
sD.findHolding("APPL").setShares(15);
```

will work. Note you need to declare `sH` as a reference too.

Answer (score 0):

Danger! In `findHolding`, `StockHolding var;` is local. Returning it as a reference will fail to do what you want and possibly go boom.

```
StockHolding& StockData::findHolding(const string &ticker) {
```

Says that the function returns a reference to a `StockHolding`.

```
 StockHolding var;
```

OK. We have a `StockHolding`. That's cool.

```
 var = portfolio[ticker];
```

Copies a `StockHolding` from `portfolio` to `var`.

```
 return var;
```

Returns a reference to local variable `var`, which is bad. `var` is about to die. But `var` only contains a copy of the data you wanted anyway. The original is in `portfolio` and will be unchanged by any modifications made to the copy. That's assuming using the now-dangling reference doesn't kill your program.

```
}
```

You likely just want

```
return portfolio[ticker];
```

Comment: Thanks, but transfer the answer check to songyuanyao. He spotted something I missed--the need for a reference on the variable catching the return--that'll get you in another minute or two.